# Add animation after removeAllAnimations doesn't work

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation

I have simple application that is the `red` view transform position form left screen to right screen. I want when I hit `remove` button, the animation will be restart (the `red` view transform position form left screen to right screen again) but it doesn't works. The `red` view back to origin frame but it's not moving, but `animationDidStop` still called after duration.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, CAAnimationDelegate {

let testView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    return view
}()

let removeAniButton : UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("Remove", for: .normal)
    return btn
}()

let addAniButton : UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    return btn
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(testView)
    testView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(removeAniButton)
    removeAniButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    removeAniButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    removeAniButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    removeAniButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    removeAniButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(addAniButton)
    addAniButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
    addAniButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    addAniButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    addAniButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    addAniButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)

    addAnimation()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func createAnimation() -> CAAnimation {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = self.view.frame.width
    animation.duration = 4
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear) 
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.delegate = self
    return animation
}

func removeAnimation(){
    testView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    testView.transform = .identity
    addAnimation()
}

func addAnimation(){
    testView.layer.add(createAnimation(), forKey: nil)
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        print("Animation is finished")
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone explain ?

Comment: You are using one property for animation and another for return to his original position, that is your issue

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong keyPath for your animation, If you want to reset your animation using `testView.transform = .identity` you need use `transform.translation.x` instead of "position.x" as animation keyPath, also is not needed call `removeAllAnimations()` only calling again your `addAnimation` will do the job

**use this code for animation creation**

```
func createAnimation() -> CAAnimation {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = self.view.frame.width
    animation.duration = 4
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    return animation
}

func removeAnimation(){
    //customView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    //customView.transform = .identity
    addAnimation()
}
```

Comment: thank you it's helped, but i wonder why I can not call 'customView.layer.removeAllAnimations()' to remove the animation ?